# jQuery Validate doesn't remove error if value is auto-inputted via JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

My HTML looks like this:

```
<form id="mainform" method="post">
    <input type="text" class="required" name="receiver" />
    <span id="clickMe">Click me</span>
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

And my JavaScript is as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#clickMe").click(function() {
        $("input[name=receiver]").val("Clicked");
    });
    $("#mainform").validate({
        submitHandler: function (form) {
            alert("Success!");
            return false;
        }
    });
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Y9RFt/2/

If you submit leaving the input empty, an error appears.

If you click the 'Click Me' span, the input is auto-filled, but the error remains until you submit the form. If you type something instead, the error disappears instantly.

Is there a way to emulate user input so that the error disappears on click?

Answer (score 3):

Simply use [the built-in `.valid()` method](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/valid) to force an immediate validation test of the form.

```
$("#clickMe").click(function () {
    $("input[name=receiver]").val("Clicked");
    $("#mainform").valid();  // <<-- Add this line to force a test
});
```

**DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/Y9RFt/8/**

Answer (score 1):

Got it. The solution is to simply blur the input:

```
$("input[name=receiver]").val("Clicked").blur();
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Y9RFt/7/

Comment: You don't need to go through all this.  Use `.valid()` inside your click handler to force a test of the form.

Comment: nice solution.. saved my time.. every time we don't need to validate whole form.

Comment: Exactly. It's less characters, no extra lines needed, and is quicker to run. I'm not sure what @Sparky means when he says "go through all this".